# how to Decrypt Files by crococrypt

Tags: security, encryption

I have encrypted files that i using crococrypt password based encryption (AES 256), I formatted my pc and now i can't decrypt them. Looks like my passwords are useless now.

I lost them forever, or there is a way to fix this ?

Comment: You had lost them forever, if the original key does not open them anymore. Perhaps, your software was using a data come from your operating system (like Windows Serial Number) or something else.

Comment: ok ty, good thing it wasn't a very important file :) and it happened now, i would have hated myself for it